# Read/copy up to a certain number of bytes from `io.Reader` to `io.Writer` in Golang, or return error if OVER a certain bytes limit?

Tags: go, io, writer, reader

I have an `io.Reader` in Golang and I want to double-check that the size of its data is below a predetermined maximum before or while running `io.Copy()` to save it to disk using `io.Writer`.

Since the file data in `io.Reader` could theoretically be quite large, I want to minimize memory usage and processing here if avoidable.
I don't think there's a function that's like `io.CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError()`, but I did notice that `io.ReadFull()` can do the opposite to return an error if not enough bytes are there to fill the provided buffer.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

---

**EDIT:**
To clarify, copying a fraction of the data is not OK. It either needs to fail if it's over the threshold, or work if it's under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `io.Reader` interface not knows anything about size or length of underlying data, there is only one solution for this problem:

You may use one buffer with maximum size `nMax` (predetermined maximum)`+1` and in every call to Your `CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError` function, inside this function read input and buffer it, and check for this buffer length, if it is less than or equal to `nMax` then do `io.Write`, otherwise return error:

```golang
const nMax = 5 // your predetermined maximum

func CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r io.Reader, w io.Writer) error {
    var buf = make([]byte, nMax+1)
    nRead, e := io.ReadFull(r, buf)
    if nRead > 0 && nRead <= nMax {
        w.Write(buf[:nRead])
        return nil
    }
    if nRead > nMax {
        return fmt.Errorf("there is more data")
    }
    return e
}
```

---

Like this working sample code unsing `string`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const nMax = 5 // your predetermined maximum

func CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r io.Reader, w io.Writer) error {
    var buf = make([]byte, nMax+1)
    nRead, e := io.ReadFull(r, buf)
    if nRead > 0 && nRead <= nMax {
        w.Write(buf[:nRead])
        return nil
    }
    if nRead > nMax {
        return fmt.Errorf("there is more data")
    }
    return e
}

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("123456789")
    err := CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r, os.Stdout)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) // there is more data
    }

    r = strings.NewReader("123\n")
    err = CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r, os.Stdout) // 123
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    r = strings.NewReader("")
    err = CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r, os.Stdout)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) // EOF
    }
}
```

output:

```
there is more data
123
EOF
```

---

Working sample code, using files:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

const nMax = 5 // your predetermined maximum

func CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r io.Reader, w io.Writer) error {
    var buf = make([]byte, nMax+1)
    nRead, e := io.ReadFull(r, buf)
    if nRead > 0 && nRead <= nMax {
        w.Write(buf[:nRead])
        return nil
    }
    if nRead > nMax {
        return fmt.Errorf("there is more data")
    }
    return e
}

func main() {
    r, err := os.Open("input.bin")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer r.Close()

    w, err := os.Create("output.bin")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer w.Close()

    err = CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r, w)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

---

Working sample code, using `[]byte`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

const nMax = 5 // your predetermined maximum

func CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r io.Reader, w io.Writer) error {
    var buf = make([]byte, nMax+1)
    nRead, e := io.ReadFull(r, buf)
    if nRead > 0 && nRead <= nMax {
        w.Write(buf[:nRead])
        return nil
    }
    if nRead > nMax {
        return fmt.Errorf("there is more data")
    }
    return e
}

func main() {
    bs := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    r := bytes.NewReader(bs)

    w := &bytes.Buffer{}

    err := CopyLessThanOrEqualToThisManyBytesOrReturnError(r, w)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done.")
    fmt.Println(w.Bytes())
}
```

output:

```
Done.
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: So to use this with an integer byte length, you'd do `r := strings.NewReader(make([] byte, 10240));` ...?

Comment: `m, e := r.Read(buf)` is not guaranteed to fill the buffer. There could be more data available that still fits within the maximum limit. Using `io.ReadFull` would be more suitable to fill the buffer as much as possible.

Comment: @Amd Honestly, it'd be nice if you named your variables. :) ... The code's hard to understand with just letters `m` and `n` for example. I had to trace them all back to see what they do.

Comment: Your examples are great, but considering it's basically the same code as @1lann in the end, I have to choose his solution given the named variables. Thanks for your help/efforts though!

Comment: Actually, yeah you're right. Now that I look at it the other does two separate operations. I'll choose this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `io.CopyN`: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyN which will return a nil error if it successfully copies exactly N bytes, or else an `io.EOF` (or possibly another error) if less than N bytes.

For example:

```
func copyMax(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader, n int64) error
    _, err := io.CopyN(dst, src, n)
    if err != nil {
        // Don't care if there's less available
        return nil
    }

    nextByte := make([]byte, 1)
    nRead, _ := io.ReadFull(src, nextByte)
    if nRead > 0 {
        // There's too much data
        return errors.New("Too much data")
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Uhh, that does the opposite I think. The goal here is to read **up to** a predetermined maximum. It's OK if it's less, but not OK if it's over. It should abort and return an error in that case.

Comment: Yes, it only reads up to N bytes. The function will return when it copies exactly N bytes. If there are less than N bytes available, it will copy as much as it can and return an error.

Comment: OK, I fixed the question title because clearly people aren't reading it. Do you see the fact that I'm asking how to avoid reading **over** a certain number of bytes, not under?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's a bummer to have to load the entire desired length + 1 into memory just for this, but at least it's temporary.